# How to move my Site Pages changes to Producation Server?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I modify the my site pages(Wiki Page) on Dev server  I want to apply this changes to Production Server. In this Page contains some new web parts added and some custom code like JavaScript code.

Please provide best way to move this changes to Production server.

Answer (score 0):

Manually by exporting web parts from DEV, and uploading and adding them in PROD. Same for the custom code: manually copy&paste changes.

Comment: Can I export hole site page from Dev and Import to Prod server it work? B'ce in my site page(wiki page) contains no of web parts. Or any command.